# What causes black dots on icons in the taskbar on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

I created an icon of a terminal with a rooster (.ico file [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JasonGross/f0685c5fb1b4705294a0d79effdc7461/raw/27f14fcc30d2c14997dde0c4b68cf5739f9b0cb8/mintty_64_rooster_all.ico)), and made a shortcut on my taskbar with target `D:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe D:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\foo.sh`, and set the icon to that .ico file.  This shortcut shows up with little black pixels overlaid on the image, and the number and location of the missing pixels varies over time (I haven't found anything in particular that will change them, but sometimes there are none, and other times the image is almost entirely covered).

Here is my taskbar with a few black pixels on the icon:
[image: Taskbar]
Cropping in on the middle icon: [image: Icon with black dots] and zooming in on it: [image: zoomed icon with black dots]
Here's another image of the icon on the taskbar, from another time: [image: Icon with more black dots] and zooming in: [image: Zoomed icon with more black dots]

But when I look at the icon in the change icon dialog box, or in an icon editor,
 no such dots appear:
[image: Change Icon dialog box]
  [image: .ico file]

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The second image isn't really zoomed in, makes it really hard to see what you're saying.

Comment: It may be Windows trying to make the icon transparent.  Try making the pixel at 1,1 in the icon a colour used nowhere else in the icon (ie: Magenta).

Comment: @djsmiley2k Added a zoomed icon.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Nope.  Interestingly, when I put a colored slash through the entire icon (a different color at each size), and change the icon on the taskbar to that new icon file, the icon on the taskbar stays the same.  (Even if I change it to a completely different icon that comes with Windows, there's no change in the icon on the taskbar, even though when I right click on it, the item in the pop-up list shows the new icon.)